# Swift - Extension UIView inside of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My intention is whenever the user tries to use the button without having all the fields filled in, to have the screen shake.

Following error appears:

> Value of type 'AddViewController' has no member 'shake'

AddViewController is of class `UIViewController`, but changing the extensions class won't work either.

```
... else {
      self.shake()
        }
```

```
extension UIView {
    func shake() {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        animation.duration = 0.6
        animation.values = [-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, -10.0, 10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 0.0 ]
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it from the vc's view as the extension is for `UIView`

```
self.view.shake()
```

To use

```
self.shakeView() // directly inside the vc
```

Do

```
extension UIViewController {
   func shakeView() {
    // .....
    // here use the view
     view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
  }
}
```